# How to add the numbers stored in Label.Text

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, int, label

I basically want to total the amount.
The amount gets stored in a label. I want to add labels. Basically I want to do an addition of labels but i can't because label is `.Text` which is `String` so when i add it I get a string of added label while i want the Numbers stored in the labels to get added. this is my code below.

```
protected void DropDownList3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    temp4 = Int32.Parse(DropDownList3.Text);
    temp5 = temp4 * 76;
    Label7.Text = temp5.ToString();
}
```

On the click of a button the amount in Lablel7 should get added with another Label.

```
protected void ImageButton3_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    Label16.Text = Label7.Text+Label6.Text;
}
```

So that the total amount can be found.

Am kinda new to programming and all itself and this is part of my project am sorry if this questions seems stupid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Label16.Text = (int.parse(Label7.Text)+int.parse(Label6.Text)).toString();
```

Use above code.

Convert your addition to string datatype.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked! Thanks a lot for such quick replies! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Parse both label's Text property to integer and then do the addition.

```
Label16.Text = (int.Parse(Label7.Text) + int.Parse(Label6.Text)).ToString();
```

Its better if you can use [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) which would save you from the exception if the text is not a number.

```
int number1;
int number2;
if(!int.TryParse(Label7.Text, out number1))
{
   // invalid number in Label7
}

if(!int.TryParse(Label6.Text, out number2))
{
   // invalid number in Label6
}

Label16.Text = (number1 + number2).ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

Label7.Text is type of string, you can add int, so you have to convert it. Afterr all you have convert back int to string

```
Label16.Text = (int.Parse(Label7.Text)+int.Parse(Label6.Text)).ToString();
```

Try to rename your controls and var. For example lblAmount tell you maore than Label6. Please read about Camel, Pascal convertion, It will help you in the future.

Comment: yeah, it can happen sometime.

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions :

1- You can parse each Text to convert into Int32, that you can add and then convert in text with ToString()

```
 protected void ImageButton3_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e) 
 { 
 Label16.Text = (Int32.Parse(Label17.Text) + Int32.Parse(Label6.Text)).ToString();
 }
```

2- On each chanching, you can save values in private properties of type Int32, and work with them.